# DAX TOPN Distinct Values

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

Say I have this data structure

| O# | Product Type | Sub Revenue | Total Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | A | $9 | $16 |
| 123 | B | $7 | $16 |
| 234 | C | $3 | $12 |
| 234 | A | $9 | $12 |
| 557 | B | $7 | $10 |
| 557 | C | $3 | $10 |

I would like to do a Top 2 (for example) by Total Revenue that would return the top 2 O# 123 and 234 like this

| O# | Product Type | Sub Revenue | Total Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | A | $9 | $16 |
| 123 | B | $7 | $16 |
| 234 | C | $3 | $12 |
| 234 | A | $9 | $12 |

How do I do it in DAX? I so far have the below but it's not quite working since it returns 123 twice and counts it as twice.

```
EVALUATE
TOPN (
    2,
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(       
        [O#],
        [Product Type],
        [Sub Revenue],
        [Total Revenue]     
    ),
    [Total Revenue],
    DESC
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
EVALUATE
FILTER (
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE (
            'Table',
            'Table'[O#],
            'Table'[Product Type],
            'Table'[Sub Revenue],
            'Table'[Total Revenue]
        ),
        "@ranking", RANKX ( 'Table', 'Table'[Total Revenue],,, DENSE )
    ),
    [@ranking] < 3
)
```

Comment: Hi - thank you for  your answer. Says "single value for the column 'Table'[O#] cannot be determined". Any ideas?

Comment: I copied your sample data into a table named "Table". I'm not sure as my data is the same as yours.

Comment: Did you copy my code exactly?

Comment: of course not :). I wrote table in my comment so it is relevant to the example above. All good - I removed the first 'Table' under SUMMARIZE and it worked. Thanks.